# Explicit formula for conformal map from ellipse to unit disc (interior to interior)

Tags: complex-analysis, conic-sections, conformal-geometry

I was originally looking for a conformal map that maps a punctured unit disc to unit disc. The only answer I can find lead to [this](https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~wwu/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?board=complex;action=display;num=1234362106) resource.

The final step of the answer given rely on a conformal map that maps an ellipse to a unit disc. Although we know such a map exist by Riemann Mapping Theorem, is there any way to write down the map explicitly (let's say, length of axes are given)?

The only related formula I can find is Joukowski transformation which does the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Joukowski map produces a slit ellipse, and is of no help here.

For a full ellipse there is no simple formula, but an interesting procedure, using the so-called *Bergman kernel*. See

Peter Henrici, *Applied and computational complex analysis*, Volume 3, Wiley 1986, pp. 529–552. The case of the ellipse is treated on p. 546 and p. 550.

Answer (score 0):

The shape of the ellipse is specified by a parameter $k$ in the range $0 < k < 1$, called the *elliptic modulus*. The *incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind* (or *inverse Jacobi AM function*) is defined as
$$
F(\phi,k) := \int_0^\phi \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}} \, .
$$
Let $c>0$ be another parameter.
Then, the following function
$$
f(z):=c \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \, \frac{F\left(\arcsin\left(k^{-\frac{1}{2}}z\right), k\right)}{F\left(\frac{\pi}{2},k\right)}\right)
$$
maps the unit disk $|z|<1$ to an elliptic region $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}<1$.

For example, if $k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, using Maple I generated the plot:
[image: Conformal map from the unit disk to an ellipse]

The parameters $k$ and $c$ can be computed from the semiaxes $a > b$ using the following formulas: $c=\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$ and
$$
k = 4 \sqrt{q} \left( \frac{(1+q^2)(1+q^4)(1+q^6)\cdots}{(1+q)(1+q^3)(1+q^5)\cdots}\right)^4 \quad \text{where } q = \left( \frac{a-b}{a+b} \right)^2 \, .
$$

Reference: H. A. Schwarz. Gesammelte mathematische Abhandlungen, Band 2. Springer, Berlin (1890), pp. 102-107 (in Italian).