# conformal structure of a disc

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces, conformal-geometry

I wonder if the conformal structure of the unit disc $D^2=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$ is unique. More precisely, given a Riemannian metric $g$ on  $D^2$, is it always true that  $g=e^{2u}g_0$, where $g_0$ is the flat metric on $D^2$? I guess this may follows from the fact that the conformal structure on the unit sphere $S^2$ is unique.

Comment: You mean *a* flat metric, right? Or $\psi^* g_0$ for some diffeomorphism $\psi$. Clearly $dx^2 + 2dy^2$ is not $e^{2u} (dx^2 + dy^2)$ for any $u$. With this correction the answer is yes - this is part of the usual uniformization theorem.

Comment: I see. I am thinking about the second one, that is, $\psi^* g_0$ for some diffeomorphism $\psi$, where $g_0=dx^2+dy^2$. But I am thinking about your example: for $g=dx^2+2dy^2$, I wonder what will be the diffeomorphism $\psi$ of $D^2$ such that $\psi^* g=g_0$. It seems that $\psi(x,y)=(x,\sqrt{2}y)$, but it is not a diffeomorphism from $D^2$ to $D^2$. Am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **uniformization theorem** says that there are exactly two conformal structures on the open unit disk $D^2$ (up to conformal mapping): The standard one and the obtained via pull-back of the conformal structure on ${\mathbb C}$ via a diffeomorphism $D^2\to {\mathbb C}$. These two structures are not conformally equivalent. However, in general, if you put some Riemannian metric on $D^2$ it is very hard (actually, usually impossible) to construct explicitly a conformal mapping to either one of the standard models. Even figuring out which one to use is not that easy. 
For instance, the one you mentioned, $g=dx^2 + 2dy^2$ is conformal to the flat metric on an ellipse, but I do not think there is a nice formula for the Riemann mapping from an ellipse to the unit disk, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1668336/explicit-formula-for-conformal-map-from-ellipse-to-unit-disc-interior-to-interi) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207934/conformal-parametrization-of-an-ellipse).